# Is it possible to make a command !messages @user

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where when someone types for example '!messages @mee6' it shows how many messages that person has said in the server. So say if I typed "a" "b" "c" then did "!messages"
the bot would reply with "@user has sent 3 messages in this server. Does anyone know if this would be possible and if so how would I go about doing it in discord.py?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by iterating over each text channel in your server and then iterating over every message in the channel. Then count the amount of messages that are sent by the user.

```
@bot.command()
async def message(ctx, user: discord.User):
  count = 0
  for channel in ctx.message.guild.text_channels:
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
      if message.author.id == user.id:
        count += 1

  await ctx.channel.send(('{} has sent {} messages').format(user.mention, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my method but i believe it will take some time to do so especially if the server is big because you are checking every channel.

```py
@bot.command()
async def messages(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None:
        # no user selected author is the user now
        user = ctx.author
    counter = 0

    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
            if message.author == user:
                counter += 1

    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has sent {counter} messages')
```

Answer (score 0):

The principle is the following:
You'd have to take advantage of the Message Received event. Once a message is received, update the counts for the person, and when the `!messages` command is ran, display the amount.

Looping through every channel in the server and filtering all messages from the user is extremely inefficient and time taking, as well as it can get your bot ratelimited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event `on_message()` so you can count messages from every user from now on.

Create a dictionary containing the users as keys and the amount of messages as values

```
users_msg = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    #If this is the first user messsage
    if message.author not in users_msg:
        users_msg[message.author] = 1

    else:
        users_msg[message.author] += 1

    if message.content.startswith("!message"):

        #Return a list containing all user mentions on the message
        user = message.mentions

        #Send the first user mention amount of messages
        await message.channel.send(f'{user[0].mention} has sent {users_msg[user[0]]}'

        #If you want so you can loop through every user mention on the command !message
        #for mentions in user:
            #await message.channel.send(f'{mentions.mention} has sent {users_msg[mentions]}')
```